# How to handle SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Everything is working in my code however if your going to create a user it will accept even if you create a multiple user with same email I already tried to search some solution and put it in my code but still I can't make it work and how can i make the SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 change into "error email already exist" ? is it possible?

addform.php

and I also want to display an error message if there is a duplicate

```
<style type="text/css">
#dis{
display:none;
}
</style>




<div id="dis">
<!-- here message will be displayed -->
</div>


 <form method='post' id='emp-SaveForm' action="#">

<table class='table table-bordered'>

    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='fname' class='form-control'  required /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='lname' class='form-control'  required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Contact Number</td>
        <td><input type='number' name='contactnum' class='form-control'  required></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type='email' name='email' class='form-control' required /></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name='pass' class='form-control'  required /></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Language</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='lang' class='form-control'  required /></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-save" id="btn-save">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Save this User
        </button>  
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

create.php

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';


if($_POST)
{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $contactnum = $_POST['contactnum'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $lang = $_POST['lang'];
    try{

        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbluser(fname,lname,contactnum,email,pass,lang) VALUES(:ufname,:ulname,:ucontact,:uemail,:upass,:ulang)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":ufname", $fname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ulname", $lname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ucontact", $contactnum);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uemail", $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":upass", $pass);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ulang", $lang);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "Successfully Added";
        }
        else{
            echo "Query Problem";
        }   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
```

I'm just new in php  I'm using PDO in database don't know if its a good thing anyway thanks for the help and please let me know if I can use or just copy paste your code or not :)

Comment: pdo is good thing

Comment: PDO is definitely a good thing. What you are missing is probably an unique index

Comment: As mentioned above me, then you're most likely missing a unique index on the email field as well - With unique index you'll automatically get a error if you try to insert a duplicate value on the unique index. One way to check for duplicate is so search for the email you want to insert BEFORE you insert it with a `SELECT`

Comment: Thanks already did what you said and I'm getting the error message SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'joe@yahoo.com' for key 'email'    can I change the error message maybe just "error adding new user email already use"? how?

Answer (score 0):

you should edit your `create.php` and add email check code from database, please check below code, to get more idea.

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';


if ($_POST) {

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $contactnum = $_POST['contactnum'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $lang = $_POST['lang'];

    // it's good habit to validate email address always 
    // i checked here it should not be blank 
    if ($email != '') {

        // check in database email address is already taken
        $sel = $db_con->prepare("select email from tbluser where email = :email");
        $sel->execute(array(':email' => $email));
        $row = $sel->fetch();

        // if you found any row with current entered email then send it to else
        if ($sel->fetchColumn() == 0) {
            try{
                $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbluser(fname,lname,contactnum,email,pass,lang) VALUES(:ufname,:ulname,:ucontact,:uemail,:upass,:ulang)");
                $stmt->bindParam(":ufname", $fname);
                $stmt->bindParam(":ulname", $lname);
                $stmt->bindParam(":ucontact", $contactnum);
                $stmt->bindParam(":uemail", $email);
                $stmt->bindParam(":upass", $pass);
                $stmt->bindParam(":ulang", $lang);
                if($stmt->execute())
                {
                    echo "Successfully Added";
                }
                else{
                    echo "Query Problem";
                }   
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            echo $email . ' already taken, try other email address';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Email address is blank';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: tried this not working still getting SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2@yahoo.com' for key 'email'

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the PDO error mode to. example:

```
/* @var $dbConn PDO */
$dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
/* set the PDO error mode to exception */
$dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then wrap your execution inside try catch to detect the error.